# Recursively filter a multidimensional array using a 2d array of whitelisted key paths including wildcards

Tags: php, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, filter

I have a multidimensional array with an indeterminant depth. I want to keep only some keys depending a collection of paths, but I need a generic, recursive function and not a hardcoded filter.

Example:

```
$originalArray = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
        'key2' => 'value2',
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'key1' => 'value3',
        'key2' => 'value4',
        'key3' => array(
            'key1' => 'value5',
            'key2' => array(
                'key1' => 'value6',
                'key2' => 'value',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'key3' => array(
        "key1" => "value1",
        "key2" => array(
            array(
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 'value2',
                'key3' => 'value2',
            ),
            array(
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key2' => 'value2',
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        )
    ),
);

$pathsToRetain = array(
    array('key1', 'key1'),
    array('key2', 'key1'),
    array('key2', 'key3', 'key1'),
    array('key2', 'key3', 'key2', 'key1'),
    array("key3", "key2", "*", 'key1'),
    array("key3", "key2", "*", 'key3')
);

$this->filterArrayByPath($originalArray, pathsToRetain);
```

Result shoud be :

```
$result = array(
    'key1' => array(
        'key1' => 'value1',
    ),
    'key2' => array(
        'key1' => 'value3',
        'key3' => array(
            'key1' => 'value5',
            'key2' => array(
                'key1' => 'value6',
            ),
        ),
    ),
    'key3' => array(
        "key2" => array(
            array(
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key3' => 'value2',
            ),
            array(
                'key1' => 'value1',
                'key3' => 'value3',
            ),
        )
    ),
);
```

One of the difficulties is on wildcard for arrays without key (key3->key2 contains arrays without keys and I want to apply the filter to both of them, or use 0, 1, 3 as key if not wildcard)

Comment: Can you please elaborate `I want to keep only some keys depending on path`, which path? How is the path being chosen? How given input evaluates to expected output?

Comment: @Adi I believe OP wants to keep the keys listed in `$pathsToRetain` which is at the bottom of the first code block.

Comment: Note that OP only has *distinct values* in the result set (duplicates are removed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've fashioned a recursive script to remove disqualified elements while modifying the input array by reference.  If you refer for the function to "return" the modified payload, you can `return $array` at the end; but just keep in mind that your original input array WILL be mutated by this function.

The demo link has some additional commented checkpoints if you'd like to see the progress internally.

The script will iterate the current level of the input array and check the first values of each row in the path array.  If a qualifying key is found, then a flag is set to not unset the element. If the element qualifies and there are more paths to traverse, then the function is called again with reduced parameters.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/dOmR0))

```
function filterArrayByPath(&$array, $pathsToRetain) {
    foreach ($array as $k => &$v) {
        $soFarSoGood = false;
        $paths = [];
        foreach ($pathsToRetain as $path) {
            $requiredKey = array_shift($path);
            if (in_array($requiredKey, ['*', $k])) {
                $soFarSoGood = true;
                if ($path) {
                    $paths[] = $path;
                } else {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        if (!$soFarSoGood) {
            unset($array[$k]);
        } elseif ($paths) {
            filterArrayByPath($v, $paths);
        }
    }
    //return $array;
}
filterArrayByPath($originalArray, $pathsToRetain);
var_export($originalArray);
// if returning the array: var_export(filterArrayByPath($originalArray, $pathsToRetain));
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer and for editing my question and making it clearer !

Comment: I just modified this line to prevent crash on accessing non existing path : `elseif ($paths && is_array($v)) { filterArrayByPath($v, $paths);}`

Comment: Please provide alternative sample input data so that I can test and review for myself.  (another 3v4l link will do nicely)

Answer (score -1):

This can be done using a recursive function.

Give this ago:

```
function filterArrayByPath($array, $pathsToRetain) {
    $filteredArray = [];

    foreach ($pathsToRetain as $path) {
        $currentArray = &$array;
        $validPath = true;

        foreach ($path as $key) {
            if ($key === '*') {
                $currentArray = array_merge_recursive($currentArray, array_fill_keys(array_keys($currentArray), []));
            } elseif (is_array($currentArray) && array_key_exists($key, $currentArray)) {
                $currentArray = &$currentArray[$key];
            } else {
                $validPath = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        if ($validPath) 
            $filteredArray = array_merge_recursive($filteredArray, $currentArray);
        
    }

    return $filteredArray;
}
```

Comment: This answer is missing its educational explanation.  Please never snippet-dump on Stack Overflow.

Comment: This answer hits a fatal error when supplied the sample data from the question body. Please test your code before posting an answer.